# Ubuntu Core 22 64 bit - Raspberry Pi 4 - SSD boot loop (full Ubuntu boots fine)

Tags: boot, ssd, raspberrypi, ubuntu-core

I'm using Raspberry Pi imager to write the provided images to SDCard/HD/SSD
Raspberry Pi 4 eeprom is upgraded to the latest version, and no sdcard is present during the issue.

**Booting Ubnt Core 22 from SDCARD and USB HD are no issue, but when I use an USB SSD drive, a boot loop occurs.
Booting the full Ubuntu 22 image from the same USB SSD drives works fine**.

How can I troubleshoot the Core boot ?
The only thing that is displayed is the color chart at boot, and a blinking cursor, after a while it just reboots, and starts this sequence all over.
I never get to the Core initial setup, also I don't see the splash screen (could be fast)

Already tried using the raspberry pi provided image, and the custom image downloaded from ubuntu download site.

Please advice on how to get the Core version to boot from my USB SSD, any help will be appreciated

Thanks,
Raf